# Django Blog Post Image

Tags: django, models

Added a featured image class which adds the ability to set a featured image for a blog post.

```
class PostFeaturedImage(models.Model):  
    last_modified = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True,editable=False)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True,editable=False)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='images/%Y/%m/%d')
    post = models.ForeignKey(Post)

    def get_image(self, field_attname):
        """Get upload_to path specific to this photo."""
        return 'photos/%Y/%m/%d' % (""" need this to make it work """)
```

images will upload to a directory like `images/2012/12/19/image.png`

I've updated admin.py and I can successfully upload and save a specific image to a blog post but I'm falling short on the knowledge to retrieve it. how can I finish `get_image` so I can get back the path to my image and then what do I use to display it? I'm thinking it would be something like...

```
{% if posts %}
    {% for post in posts %}
        {% if postfeaturedimage %}
         <img src="{{post.postfeaturedimage.get_image}}" alt="{{post.postfeaturedimage.title}}">
        {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

I'm terribly new to Django and feel like I'm making major progress but I'm still slipping on some details.

Comment: The date is suppose to be from the creation date?

Comment: Yes. I'm
 trying to keep them archived much like how WordPress does it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this

```
def get_image(self):
    """Get upload_to path specific to this photo."""
    return self.image.url
```

Also your `if` condition for `PostFeaturedImage` in template should be `{% if post.postfeaturedimage %}` instead of `{% if postfeaturedimage %}`

Comment: actually you don't need to write a custom model method for this. You can call `{{ post.postfeaturedimage.url }}` directly in the template.

Comment: I gave answer according to what questioner asked for. Obviously `post.postfeaturedimage.image.url` is a shorter version.

Comment: Also sometime image method is handy. e.g. return the image url if present else send default image url.

Comment: That doesn't seem to work. Do you need to see what I have in my admin.py or template file?

Comment: Have you fixed the `if` condition which I mentioned? Also what doesn't seem to work? Is the url is wrong or is it empty or what?

Comment: I used `{% if post.postfeaturedimage %}` and `{{ post.postfeaturedimage.get_image }}` but it must be returning false because with the conditional no image box displays (the class style draws a box), without the conditional I still have no url for the img src

Answer (score 2):

the get_image function is unnecessary. You can reach the image url from the template like that:

```
{{ post.postfeaturedimage.image.url }}
```